# Can i do processing in video with Python?

Tags: python, video, image-processing, opencv

I am starting to do a task which involves detecting a feature in a video, i have to detect red colour regions of a rectangle shape and replace with another colour. Can i go ahead doing this in python with "opencv" interface ?

Comment: http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, OpenCV already have an interface for python through swighPythonInterface

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PythonInterface

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/SwigPythonInterface

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.  Converting to the HSV colour space is good for finding red in an image, and the Hough transform will help you find rectangles

Comment: i have one more question to you, i know that i am actually supposed to post this as a separate question, but can you tell me if my approach is right as i am really new to image processing.. step 1) capture each frame 2) on each frame loop over pixels and replace the colour if it matches. Is this right ? Will the looping over pixels take a long time ?

Comment: I wouldn't loop over all of the pixels.  You just want to replace red rectangular regions, right?  First, convert your image to HSV space and evaluate which hue and saturation values give the approximate colour you're looking for.  Once you have that range, binarize your image such that pixels are black if they meet your red criteria and white otherwise.  Finally, use OpenCVs Hough transform to find the rectangles.  That's the simplest way, a good starting point.  Hopefully this suffices, answering from my phone, so I can't provide links

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate for so such a detailed description. Will go ahead and try this out. :)